# i'm trying to install cutefish os on my ubuntu which is the version is 22.04 kinetic, but when i followed the tutorial, i get error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, gnu-make, cmake-gui

based on the following tutorial https://github.com/cutefish-ubuntu/cutefish-desktop-ubuntu
when at the step 3, which is the instruction

```
cd ~/Downloads/cutefish
git clone https://github.com/cutefishos/kwin-plugins
cd kwin-plugins
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b
```

i get the following message at the end of the process

```
/home/rogan/Downloads/cutefish/kwin-plugins/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/plugins/roundedwindow/roundedwindow_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/../../../../../plugins/roundedwindow/roundedwindow.h:36:36: error: ‘LanczosCacheRole’ is not a member of ‘KWin::DataRole’
   36 |         BaseRole = KWin::DataRole::LanczosCacheRole + 100,
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [plugins/roundedwindow/CMakeFiles/roundedwindow.dir/build.make:87: plugins/roundedwindow/CMakeFiles/roundedwindow.dir/roundedwindow_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rogan/Downloads/cutefish/kwin-plugins/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:269: plugins/roundedwindow/CMakeFiles/roundedwindow.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rogan/Downloads/cutefish/kwin-plugins/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:139: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rogan/Downloads/cutefish/kwin-plugins/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
dh_auto_build: error: cd obj-x86_64-linux-gnu && make -j1 VERBOSE=1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [debian/rules:6: build] Error 255
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
```

I don't know what it is, but it looks like it was an installation failure

is it cause iam using wrong version of ubuntu distro?
if yes, there is another way to install cutefish os on ubuntu 22.04 kinetic?

Comment: This seems like something you should be filing an issue about on the GitHub project site, not asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: Already reported by someone else: https://github.com/cutefishos/kwin-plugins/issues/15, but no one reply.

Comment: This is caused by [a KWin update](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/kwin/-/commit/683a222233f69897bf3455372bab01e3f3d56fb4#bf2f5339f343c01a37afa74729fb3ecb21357f11_202_202), not Ubuntu 22.04.